# I was trying to implement a object detection on a custom dataset using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am new to tensorflow and I was following this [link]https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

I ran the
`python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config`

and I was getting a error like this and the program stopped.

WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issue
s. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check expli
cit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.

Here are some errors

```
W0817 10:14:35.677110 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.0.1.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.0.kernel
W0817 10:14:35.682097 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.0.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.axis
W0817 10:14:35.682097 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.gamma
W0817 10:14:35.683094 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.beta
W0817 10:14:35.683094 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.moving_mean
W0817 10:14:35.683094 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.moving_variance
W0817 10:14:35.684094 16272 util.py:150] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._feature_extractor._fpn_features_generator.conv_layers.1.1.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issue
s. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check expli
cit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W0817 10:14:35.684094 16272 util.py:158] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See ab
ove for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() t
o make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
```

some background:
I am using windows 10
I installed tensorflow gpu
I am using tenforflow 2.3.0

Comment: I didn't see any issues in output and all those are warnings, you can ignore them. If you are observing this output then you have successfully started your first training job.

Comment: If you are not seeing output similar to shown above and the training job crashes after a few seconds, then have a look at the issues and proposed solutions [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issues.html#issues)

Comment: You can check [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) for factors that affects to increase training time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I removed all the previously present checkpoints from the `models` folder inside the `workspace`, it started to work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).